# Setup encrypted LVM on ubuntu 18.04 server edition

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, filesystem, encryption, lvm

While installing Ubuntu 18.04 server edition, the option "Use entire disk and setup encrypted LVM" is missing

[image: Screenshot]

So how do encrypt the entire disk while installing server edition?

Comment: I need to protect data-at-rest. It's standard protocol while using servers containing sensitive data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the solution.

I was using ubuntu-18.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso which does not have this option. Encryption option is present in ubuntu-18.04.1-server-amd64.iso

[image]

The installers for live-server and server are entirely different.

Comment: I had the same issue. For Ubuntu LTS 18.04, go directly to: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/